# Ag-grid how to override Set Filter matching

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid with Tree data and one column using a set filter (agSetColumnFilter). I want to override the set filter to only apply to parent nodes at the very top.

for example if I have this data:

```
A1
 -> A1
 -> A2
B1
 -> A1
 -> B1
```

and I filter by A1, I will get both A1 and B1 groups displayed (with child nodes that aren't A1 filtered out), but I just want A1 group to show and all children to be visible.

I can't see anything in the documentation about adjusting the matching of the Set Filter, the best solution I can find is creating a custom filter. But I would rather avoid this since I want the Set filter to behave and look exactly like it does now, with only one small adjustment to the matching logic, so creating a custom filter seems like a lot of unnecessary work.

Is there any way to adjust the set filter logic, or do I have to make a custom filter from scratch?

Comment: I ended up just going through the trouble of making the custom filter in order to achieve what I need. Feels incredibly unnecessary but as far as I can see it's the only option. If anyone is aware of a workaround that I'm missing I'd still be interested to hear it so I can simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

Let try my way to override Set Filter matching:

```
const colComponent = gridOption.api.getFilterInstance('columnName')
colComponent.doesFilterPass = function(params) {
    // Get filter values
    const valuesSelected = colComponent.getModel()
    // Your logic
    // Return true if matching
    return
}
```